# How to make function pointers in a structure constant to be used to initialise a constant array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, constants

I have the following constant struct which holds function pointers:

```
/* module1.h */

typedef struct my_struct my_struct_t;

struct my_struct
{
   void (*funcPtr1)(void);
   void (*funcPtr2)(void);
}

extern const my_struct_t myStruct1;



/* module1.c */

#include <module1.h>

static void func1(void)
{
   // do something
}

static void func2(void)
{
   // do something else
}

const my_struct_t myStruct1 = {
   .funcPtr1 = &func1,
   .funcPtr2 = &func2
}
```

So far so good!

Now I want to create a constant array of the above struct and assign the function pointers from instances of the struct:

```
/* module2.c */

#include <module1.h>

const my_struct_t arrayOfMyStruct[] = {
   { myStruct1.funcPtr1, myStruct1.funcPtr2 },
   // ...
}
```

Compiler throws an error and says, that the expressions `"myStruct1.funcPtr1"` and `"myStruct1.funcPtr2"` were not constant.
What is wrong?

Comment: are you sure <module1.h> is included. For including local file `#include "module1.h"`.

Comment: It is surely included.

Comment: This not an issue related to function-pointers but an issue related to initalisation of variables in general.

Comment: @Jeyaram The initialization is correct. It is an array of structs.

Answer (score 2):

`myStruct1` is declared with the qualifier const, but it isn't constant. Static initialization requires it to be, and `arrayOfMyStruct` has static storage duration.

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

You can initialize it by using the functions directly: `{ func1, func2 },`

or take the address of the pointer: `{ &myStruct1.funcPtr1, &myStruct1.funcPtr2 },`

in which case you will have to use a different struct type for the array:

```
typedef struct 
{
   void (*const *funcPtr1)(void);
   void (*const *funcPtr2)(void);
} my_struct2_t;
```

And syntax for calling the function has to be changed:

```
(*arrayOfMyStruct[0].funcPtr2)();
```

Comment: The first solution is not possible in my application. In fact the type of the array in module2.c is another type but it holds the same function pointer types so I used the same to explain the problem. <EDIT: here comes the part that is covered now by your edit:> By the second solution you mean that I have to change the struct for module2.c in that way that it handles a "pointer to a function pointer", right? But I don't want to change that actually. Isn't there any way to make the "myStruct1.funcPtr1" constant??

Comment: @momjovi89  Apart from the ways listed above. No.